# How to fix DNS lame referral error for popular domain such as registry-1.docker.io

Tags: docker, dns

> docker pull ubuntu
>   Using default tag: latest
>   Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: lame referral

My /etc/resolv.conf shows :
nameserver 8.8.8.8

dig seems fine though, its only when I do docker pull

Comment: is there anything strange in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: nothing strange. what does lame referral mean?